# Why doesn't this function signature typecheck?

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking

Why doesn't `extractEither` typecheck?

```
data MyEither a b = MyLeft a | MyRight b
                    deriving (Read, Show)

extractEither :: MyEither a b -> c
extractEither (MyLeft p) = p
```

The compiler shows:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `c'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for extractEither :: MyEither a b -> c
      at /Users/tongmuchenxuan/playground/test.hs:5:1
  `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for extractEither :: MyEither a b -> c
      at /Users/tongmuchenxuan/playground/test.hs:5:1
In the expression: p
In an equation for `extractEither': extractEither (MyLeft p) = p
```

Isn't `c' general enough to catch any type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. `c` is *any type the caller could wish the function to return*, i.e. for a function `f :: a -> c` it would *always* need to be possible to write `f x + 1 :: Int` as well as `putStr $ f x` as well as `main = f x`. Which your function does of course not permit.

What you want is returning a dynamic type. Haskell deliberately does not permit this as easily as some other languages do, because it obviously can lead to runtime errors easily when the returned type is something unexpected. There are various ways to do it, but which is the right one depends on what you actually want this for. Could you give some context? It's likely that the best solution to your problem would *not* use dynamic types, but something more Haskell-idiomatic.

Perhaps what you want is simply

```
extractEither :: MyEither a a -> a
extractEither (MyLeft p) = p
extractEither (MyRight p) = p
```

which requires that the types on both "sides" are the same.

Comment: Thanks. Both of your two's answers are clear and solve my puzzle!

Comment: Actually the question doesn't presuppose dynamic typing, but just subtyping and upcasts, which AFAIK can be statically checked.  Haskell doesn't have these, though.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, your type signature says your function may return a value of any type `c` given a `MyEither a b`, again, for every `a` and `b`. However, as the compiler points out, it's not possible to produce any such `c` here, as you're actually returning a value of type `a` (being `p :: a`).

Furthermore, your definition still do not manage the case in which your `MyEither a b` is not a `Left a`. What should it do, e.g., when you call `extractEither (MyRight 1)`? If you try to run a function like that (after correcting the type signature of course), you may incur in what is called a *non-exhaustive pattern* exception, meaning there's no body definition for `extractEither` to handle some possible input patterns.

If you're trying to write a single function that works both for extracting the `MyLeft` and the `MyRight` values, I'm afraid you should change your mind. In order to extract whatever, left or right, you should have the same type on both sides (i.e. `MyEither a a`), which is not so useful.

You should consider to have functions like these in order to extract values. Here, I return `Maybe` to avoid the burden of managing calls to `error` when for example you try to extract a left from a right value:

```
extractMyLeft :: MyEither a b -> Maybe a
extractMyRight :: MyEither a b -> Maybe b
```

**edit:** see also dblhelix's answer for a suggestion on another possible refactoring that may be useful to *almost* obtain the type signature you was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Riccardo's answer: if you want a function that is able to extract a value of some type `c` from a `MyEither` value no matter whether it is built by `MyLeft` or `MyRight`, you could, rather than requiring that the value has type `MyEither c c`, "instruct" the function on how to obtain a `c`-typed value from either side:

```
extractEither :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> MyEither a b -> c
extractEither f g (MyLeft x)  = f x
extractEither f g (MyRight y) = g y
```

That is, `extractEither` now takes two additional arguments `f` and `g`: functions that are used to take the extracted values to values of the required type.

This is a very common and useful idiom when working with sum types.

Comment: I'm gonna add a line in my answer to reference yours. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I have to specify both f and g, right? Is there a way to specify only one of them and say something like "I don't care what another is"--Something like `_' in pattern matching.

Comment: Yes, you can: `extractEither undefined id (MyRight 3.14)`, but then you better be sure that you don't supply a value built with `MyLeft`. ;)

Comment: hIt's worth noting that `extractEither` is defined in `Data.Either` simply as `either`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that its type corresponds the elimination rule for logical disjunction: "if it is the case that if `a` then `c`, then if it is the case that if `b` then `c`, then if `a` or `b` then `c`." Generic types that have terminating functions correspond to logical tautologies. Compare to the original type in the question: "if `a` or `b`, then `c`" (e.g., "If George Washington was the first President of the USA or the Battle of Stalingrad started in 1942, then Napoleon Bonaparte shot John F. Kennedy").

Answer (score 1):

```
extractEither :: MyEither a b -> c
extractEither (MyLeft p) = p
```

> Isn't `c' general enough to catch any type?

The intuition you're bringing to the table works in object-oriented languages or other languages with subtyping, but not in Haskell or other parametric typing systems (e.g., Java generic).  Take this method signature in Java:

```
public Object blah(Foo whatever);
```

This method returns `Object`, which is the highest type in the hierarchy.  This means that an implementation of this method can choose to return any type it wants, and it will be trivially upcast to `Object`.

Haskell types don't work like that.  You're thinking that your `extractFilter` can just return `p` because you're implicitly assuming that **you**, the author of `extractEither`, get to pick which type to use for `c`, just like the author of `blah` gets to pick the runtime type of the result.  But in Haskell it's the other way around: the **caller** of your function gets to pick the types to use for `a`, `b` and `c`, and they can choose an incompatible `a` and `c`.  If I pick any `a` ≠ `c`, there is no terminating piece of code you can write to turn my arbitrary choice of `a` into my arbitrary choice of `c`.